# Can't retrieve DATETIME column in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am getting datetime value from sqlite:

todoDAO.java

```
Public String text(String dd) {
    String[] tableColumns = new String[] { "datetime" };

    // Query the database
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    // Iterate the results
    Todo todo = new Todo();
    String millis = todo.setdate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date_time")));
    SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",Locale.getDefault()) ;
    Date date = null;

    try {
        date = format.parse(millis);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return date;
}
```

By using this am getting datetime and storing in setdate as below activity.

activity.java

```
public String getdate() {
    return date;
}

public String setdate(String date) {
    return this.date = date;
}
```

After storing it, I am retrieving it from getdate as above activity.

Then in mainactivity.class

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String time =new String();
                Todo todo = new Todo();
                time =todo.getdate();

                 dao.text(time);
                Toast.makeText(
                        getBaseContext(),
                         + time, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        });
```

Now I am getting a null value from string `time`

Please help me why i am not getting then correct value. Where is the mistake?

Comment: Post complete logcat and point out where you are getting null pointer exception.

Comment: This looks similar to your earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24593093/cant-retrive-datetime-column-in-sqlite-for-alarmmanager - please edit the original instead of posting a new question.

Comment: S @laalto am edited now..

Comment: The problem is in line 53 of `AddTodoActivity.java`. You have to show that code and tell which line this is.

Comment: i have edited the question plz answer for it...